# Assinging 1 character from 1 list to another python

Tags: list, python-2.7

Hi i am making a decryption machine for my school project but i cant get it to work can you guys help me out?
Thanks already.

the error is: line 17, IndexError: list index out of range
The length of zin = 86 just so you know

this is what is in the file i need to decrypt: KEIGO N JIDOUBANEUOFIDNEIESUN  IRAEI  ESTIGIVNKMUEEER RDONAEOIW ENEZAEE NAML VN NILLRA

```
with open('something.txt', 'r') as fhandle:

key = 3

#reading the file
zin = list(fhandle.readline())

#setting up solution to which we will output
solution = list(" ")*86
solution[0] = zin[0]

#while loop in which we use the key to decrypt the message
i = 1
while i < len(zin):
    solution[i] = zin[key] #this is where i get the error
    i += 1
    key += key
    if i > 86:
        break

print(solution)
```

Comment: You need to add the error to this question. It look like at some point `zin` has a length shorter than 3, hence you get an IndexError, but this is a guess.

Comment: Then the best thing to to would be to put a print statement above the line `solution[i] = zin[key]` that reads `print len(zin)`. That will tell you that what you are reading from file with `zin = list(fhandle.readline())` is probably not what you expect.

Comment: use fhandle.readlines() instead which gives u full list of lines. fhandle.readline() gives only first line of the file.

Comment: Why do you hardcode the `86`? What if the length of `zin` is different? Also, unless I'm mistaken you double `key` in each iteration of the loop, i.e. after `i` iteration, `key` is `key*2^i`, which is clearly larger than the length of `zin`. Did you mean `zin[key % len(zin)]`?

Comment: i runned it and printed after each re-loop. i noticed that at some point key became bigger than 86 which is the length of the sentence. so now i need to know how i can get key count past 86 and start at 0

Comment: It would help to know what algorithm that's supposed to be...

Comment: transpostional algorithm i guess

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that so far. But what are the rules of the transposition?

Comment: guys i almost got it i just need to know how i can count past 86 starting again at 0 so when it is at 85 and i do + 3 it goes to 1

Comment: As I said, try `zin[key % len(zin)]`, but that does not seem to decypher the text. Also, the length of the text is 84, not 86.

Comment: ty for the reply i fixed the issue but now i need to know todo something like if i > 86 and then to get it to count from 0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing `zin[key]`,  you need to verify length of `zin` is at least `key+1`.